# Being driven mad by adding a header to a page containing navigation function/indicators

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am adapting a Javascript/JQuery function for a vertical navigation dots indicator. My problem is that I need to allow room for a responsive header above the body content. The styling of the dot indicators (to make them solid or not) is based on the each content div arriving at the top of the page, when in reality I need them to arrive at the top of the page allowing for the height of the responsively sized header above.

I imagine it's a very simple case of adding my variable 'height' into the 2 functions, but all the combinations I have tried don't make sense, even when I have written what each function does in the comments.

Anyone with a better brain able to advise

```
// vertical position of scroll bar
var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

// height of the broswer window
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

// height of the document
var docHeight = $(document).height();           

//height of the header image 
var img = document.getElementById('logoimage'); 
var height = img.clientHeight;

for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    var theID = aArray[i];
    var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; 
    var divHeight = $(theID).height(); 


    // 1st Function - if (position of scrollbar is bigger or equal to the position of the div) AND (position of scrollbar is less than (position of the div added to the height of the div)

    if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
        $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("name-active");
    } else {
        $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("name-active");
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you show result you are getting with HTML and CSS

Comment: Thanks Arun, I wasn't sure that was required - as I scroll, the indicators change as expected, but only when the content reaches the top of the page (which means underneath the header)